# Shipping Templates Zend PDF Generator Permissions Denied

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, permissions

When I try to create a shipping label in Magento Commmunity Edition 1.9, I'm facing a permissions error in system.log:

> Warning: imagepng(/var/folders/f3/pd3xtxvd0y390_qjv7pryv6m0000gn/T/shipping_labels_11721274915437009a686f81412890778.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_site/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php on line 732

I am also faced with the following error in exceptions.log:

> exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Cannot create image resource. File not found.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_site/lib/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php:38
>
> Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fswings/lib/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('/var/folders/f3...')

As well as the less informative error on the front-end:

> An error occurred while creating shipping label.

I've set my permissions site-wide (while developing) to 755 for folders and 644 for files.  I tried several things to see if this is indeed a permissions issue:

- I've **temporarily** set permissions on ShipmentController.php to 777
- I've **temporarily** set permissions recursively on the var folder to 777
- When that didn't work, I tried setting permissions recursively on the whole project file to 777
- I've tried to disable and enable the cache, as well as flushing it

My theory is the pdf generator Zend uses is unable to write to var, as I do not see a var/folders directory.

Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves correct Zend pdf has issues when working with magento 1.9 on php 5.4 or 5.5.

Go to

> /lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php

and remove

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

this should resolve your issue.

Comment: My installation of Magento (1.9.0.1) did not have that line of code in that file.  Perhaps they removed it?  I downgraded my server to PHP 5.3 and face the same error.  This looks like it's a permissions issue?

Comment: Go to System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Run Compilation Process button or Disable button. sometimes recompiling your magento installation will fix missing file issues

Comment: I've tried running the compilation process and disabling it and still get the same error.  This must be an issue with my localized server (I'm running MAMP) as it works when I host it live.  I'm trying to see if there's any other info I can find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my "TMPDIR" not being writeable on my local installation (I'm using MAMP).  To solve this problem, I've created a info.php file with the phpinfo function:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

I found the TMPDIR directory it was trying to access under the "Environment" section of the PHP Info.  From there, I went into my filesystem and changed the permissions of "/var/folders" (on my local computer) to allow writing recursively and it worked.